# summarising and aggregating column values as rows in R

Tags: r, statistics, reshape2

My  data frame contains mostly catagorical columns and one numerical column, The df looks like this(simplified):

```
**Home_type**     **Garden_type**       **NaighbourhoOd**    **Rent** 
Vila                big                  brooklyn             5000
Vila                small                bronx                7000
Condo               shared               Sillicon valley      2000 
Appartment          none                 brooklyn             500
Condo               none                 bronx                1700
Appartment          none                 Sillicon Valley      800
```

For every catagorical column, I want to display all its distinct values, frequency and sum of rent associated with it.

The result should look like this:

```
**Variable**     **Distinct_values**      **No_of-Occurences**     **SUM_RENT**
  Home_type        Vila                     2                        12000
  Home_type        Condo                    2                        3700
  Home_type        Appartment               2                        1300
  Garden_type      big                      1                        5000
  Garden_type      small                    1                        7000
  Garden_type      shared                   1                        2000 
  Garden_type      none                     3                        3000 
  Naighbourhood    brooklyn                 2                        5500
  Naighbourhood    Bronx                    2                        8700 
  Naighbourhood    Sillicon Valley          2                        2800
```

I'm new to R and have tried to do this using melt in reshape2 but havent had much success, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look at [this overview for asking good R questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), particularly at the portions that give ways to easily read your data in. It is a lot easier to help if we don't have to fight to read your data into R.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out to me Mark, I will definitely be more careful in the future and will edit this post later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to prefer `tidyr` to `reshape2` of late, though that is mostly because the syntax is more similar to `dplyr` -- which will make this task even easier as well due to loading the `magrittr` pipe (`%>%`) and it's data summary tools.

First, we `gather` (from `tidyr`) all of the non-Rent columns into long form (run just those two lines to see the result). Then `group_by` the columns you want to cluster together. Finally, `summarise` within each group to get the metrics you want.

```
df %>%
  gather(Variable, Distinct_Values, -Rent) %>%
  group_by(Variable, Distinct_Values) %>%
  summarise(
    `No_of-Occurences` = n()
    , SUM_RENT = sum(Rent)
  )
```

gives:

```
        Variable Distinct_Values `No_of-Occurences` SUM_RENT
           <chr>           <chr>              <int>    <int>
1    Garden_type             big                  1     5000
2    Garden_type            none                  3     3000
3    Garden_type          shared                  1     2000
4    Garden_type           small                  1     7000
5      Home_type      Appartment                  2     1300
6      Home_type           Condo                  2     3700
7      Home_type            Vila                  2    12000
8  NaighbourhoOd           bronx                  2     8700
9  NaighbourhoOd        brooklyn                  2     5500
10 NaighbourhoOd Sillicon valley                  1     2000
11 NaighbourhoOd Sillicon Valley                  1      800
```

(Note, your data has "V" and "v" for "Silicon Valley" causing the two separate lines.)

Comment: Works great, thankyou.
I wasn't aware about tidyr, will definitely be using more of it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`. Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `melt` from 'wide' to 'long' format, grouped by 'variable', 'value' (columns created from the `melt`), we create two columns 'No_of_occur', 'SUM_RENT' as the number of rows (`.N`) and `sum` of 'Rent' column, and then grouped by 'variable', 'No_of_occur' and 'SUM_RENT', get the `unique` elements of 'value' column ('Distinct_values')

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), id.var=c('Rent'))[, c("No_of_occur", "SUM_RENT") :=
      .(.N, sum(Rent)) ,.(variable, value)][,
    .(Distinct_values = unique(value)) , .(variable, No_of_occur, SUM_RENT)]
 #         variable No_of_occur SUM_RENT Distinct_values
 #1:     Home_type           2    12000            Vila
 #2:     Home_type           2     3700           Condo
 #3:     Home_type           2     1300      Appartment
 #4:   Garden_type           1     5000             big
 #5:   Garden_type           1     7000           small
 #6:   Garden_type           1     2000          shared
 #7:   Garden_type           3     3000            none
 #8: NaighbourhoOd           2     5500        brooklyn
 #9: NaighbourhoOd           2     8700           bronx
 #10:NaighbourhoOd           2     2800 Sillicon Valley
```